Envelope solutions
This is my first post. I try to calculate the curve length of an envelope.
The equation of the curve is giving by :
$\begin{pmatrix}
x_M \\
y_M
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
x_T(\phi) \\
y_T(\phi)
\end{pmatrix}
+
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\phi) && \sin(\phi) \\
-\sin(\phi) && \cos(\phi)
\end{pmatrix}
\times
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\rho}{\cos(\beta_0)}\times\cos(\zeta) \\
\rho\times\sin(\zeta)
\end{pmatrix}$
$x_T$ and $y_T$ are derivable functions dependant to the parameter $\phi$.
$\rho$ and $\beta_0$ are constant.
After some research $\zeta$ is giving by the folowing relation :
$A\times\tan(\zeta)+B\times\sin(\zeta)=C$
Where :
$A=\frac{x_T'(\phi)\times\sin(\phi)+y_T'(\phi)\times\cos(\phi)}{\cos(\beta_0)}$
$B=\rho\times(1-\frac{1}{\cos^2(\beta_0)})$
$C=y_T'(\phi)\times\sin(\phi)-x_T'(\phi)\times\cos(\phi)$
I want to calculate the length of the curve described by $x_M$, $y_M$ but I don't have direct relation between the parameter $\phi$ and the parameter $\zeta$. And I can't use this formula :
$\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{\frac{\partial x_M}{\partial \phi} + \frac{\partial y_M}{\partial \phi}} \,d\phi$
My question is :
How to calculate analytically the length of the curve described by $x_M$, $y_M$ ?
Thanks for your help.
